# One variable is breaking my simple program, why?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm following a tutorial and trying to modify some code. As the code currently stands, everything is in working order to have a ball bounce around a square and off a paddle at the bottom and all I want to do is make the ball bigger when it bounces off the paddle. The balls starts at size 15 and I can increment it by 1-4 but at 5 and beyond, there is a bug that causes the ball to stay in location and grow to half the screen and then just stay there. I think as it grows it clips back into the hitbox for the paddle and then activates another growth and repeat. However, I am totally unsure. Can anyone shed some light? I will put a capitalized comment on the variable responsible halfway down the code. Thank you very much for any assistance!

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var x = canvas.width / 2; //starting coordinates
var y = canvas.height - 30;

var dx = 2; //rate of movement for ball
var dy = -2;

var ballRadius = 15;

var paddleHeight = 10;
var paddleWidth = 75;
var paddleX = (canvas.width - paddleWidth) / 2;

var rightPressed = false;
var leftPressed = false;

function drawBall() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, ballRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#ff0000";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}

function drawPaddle() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(paddleX, canvas.height - paddleHeight, paddleWidth, paddleHeight);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  drawBall();
  drawPaddle();
  x += dx;
  y += dy;

  if (x + dx > canvas.width - ballRadius || x + dx < ballRadius) { //these ifs cause the ball to bounce off walls
    dx = -dx;
  }

  if (y + dy < ballRadius) {
    dy = -dy;
  } else if (y + dy > canvas.height - ballRadius) {
    if (x > paddleX && x < paddleX + paddleWidth) { //detects paddlebox detection
      dy = -dy;
      ballRadius += 7; //TROUBLESOME VARIABLE! Work with 1-4 but breaks beyond that.

    } else {
      alert("GAME OVER");
      document.location.reload();
    }
  }
  if (rightPressed && paddleX < canvas.width - paddleWidth) {
    paddleX += 7;
  } else if (leftPressed && paddleX > 0) {
    paddleX -= 7;
  }
}
document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, false);

function keyDownHandler(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 39) {
    rightPressed = true;
  } else if (e.keyCode == 37) {
    leftPressed = true;
  }
}

function keyUpHandler(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 39) {
    rightPressed = false;
  } else if (e.keyCode == 37) {
    leftPressed = false;
  }
}

setInterval(draw, 10);
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

canvas {
  background: #eee;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="480" height="320"></canvas>
```

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of paragraphs and why people use them?

Comment: After you grow the ball, the `draw()` function runs again 10 ms later, and it's still hitting the paddle. So it grows it again, and this keeps repeating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that your draw function excecutes every 10ms. So when your ball hits the paddle it actually triggers the ball to grow multiple number of times. My solution was to how a timeout/delay when you increase the size of the ball so that it has time to move away before the next time the draw function fires. Heres the code.

NOTE : Open up the snippet in full screen to view the game better

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var x = canvas.width / 2; //starting coordinates
var y = canvas.height - 30;

var dx = 2; //rate of movement for ball
var dy = -2;

var ballRadius = 15;

var paddleHeight = 10;
var paddleWidth = 75;
var paddleX = (canvas.width - paddleWidth) / 2;

var rightPressed = false;
var leftPressed = false;

function drawBall() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, ballRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#ff0000";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}

function drawPaddle() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(paddleX, canvas.height - paddleHeight, paddleWidth, paddleHeight);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  drawBall();
  drawPaddle();
  x += dx;
  y += dy;

  if (x + dx > canvas.width - ballRadius || x + dx < ballRadius) { //these ifs cause the ball to bounce off walls
    dx = -dx;
  }

  if (y + dy < ballRadius) {
    dy = -dy;
  } else if (y + dy > canvas.height - ballRadius) {
    if (x > paddleX && x < paddleX + paddleWidth) { //detects paddlebox detection
      dy = -dy;
      setTimeout(function(){ ballRadius += 7; }, 100);
       

    } else {
      alert("GAME OVER");
      document.location.reload();
    }
  }
  if (rightPressed && paddleX < canvas.width - paddleWidth) {
    paddleX += 7;
  } else if (leftPressed && paddleX > 0) {
    paddleX -= 7;
  }
}
document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, false);

function keyDownHandler(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 39) {
    rightPressed = true;
  } else if (e.keyCode == 37) {
    leftPressed = true;
  }
}

function keyUpHandler(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 39) {
    rightPressed = false;
  } else if (e.keyCode == 37) {
    leftPressed = false;
  }
}

setInterval(draw, 10);
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

canvas {
  background: #eee;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="480" height="320"></canvas>
```